# Send is not a function discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with version 12 of discord JavaScript.
I get this error but I changed the find function.
What else can he have?

```
upBot.send is not a function
```

```
let upBot = bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id = "");
    let upBotEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colours.red_light)
        .addField(`${bot.user.username} online`, datetime)
        .setFooter(`Test`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL);
        upBot.send(upBotEmbed).then(m => m.delete(900000))
```

Comment: We can't help you; `upSend` is not called on anywhere in the code you gave us.

Comment: Sorry, upBot.send

Comment: That means the channel ID is incorrect or the channel is not cached by the bot.

Comment: Id is correct ...

Comment: Is this in your ready event?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are not using the delete timeout correctly.

Change

```js
.delete(900000)
```

to

```js
.delete({ timeout: 900000 })
```

The delete property takes an object in version v12.

Answer (score 0):

`find` function should returns a list of object. Try this:

```
...
for(const upBot of upBots) {
    upBot.send(upBotEmbed).then(m => m.delete(900000))
}
```